# append extra text to select options

Tags: jquery

After investigating several methods to manipulate select menu options and cant get my head around the correct way , i try it here.

I have the following fiddle representing partial working code:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j77rM/)

Currently if re-select an option, it duplicates the text, but beside that unwanted effect , i actual want all options directly replaced.

The default code i use:

```
//START Get the stockdata

$stock_array = array();
$products_stock_query=tep_db_query("SELECT *
                                  FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_STOCK . " 
                                  WHERE products_id=" . (int)$HTTP_GET_VARS['products_id'] ." 
                                  ORDER BY products_stock_attributes");

while($products_stock_values=tep_db_fetch_array($products_stock_query)) {
$str = $products_stock_values['products_stock_attributes'];
$str = substr( $str, ( $pos = strpos( $str, '-' ) ) === false ? 0 : $pos + 1 );
echo '<div class="stockdata" valuestock="'.$products_stock_values['products_stock_quantity'].'" valueid="'.$str.'"></div>';
}
?>

<script>

$('option').each(function () {
    $(this).data('txt', $(this).text());

});
$('select').change(function () {
var str = "";
$( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
 str += this.text;
    $('option', this).each(function () {
        $(this).text($(this).data('txt'));
    });
    });
    var myCheck = $("body").find("div[valueid=" + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value') + "]").attr("valuestock");
    if (myCheck === '0'){
    //do nothing
    }else{
   // $(this).find('option:selected').text($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'));
    $(this).find('option:selected').text(str + ' (' +  $("body").find("div[valueid=" + $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value') + "]").attr("valuestock")+') <?php echo IN_STOCK_ATT; ?>');
}
}).trigger( "change" );

</script>
```

Comment: FYI, instead of using hidden DIVs to store relative data, use data-* attribute set directly on options, would be better

Comment: i am aware of the data attributes , but in this code i cant implement them.i already did some test with it.There is also no way to update jquery to the latest version as it will break a few other js codes.it is a dirty trick i have to use.

Comment: Well, data-attribute is quite well supported: http://caniuse.com/dataset

Comment: You have a `$('option', this).each(function() {..})` inside of `$("select option:selected").each(function () {})`. What is this? o.o

Comment: BTW, if you want to set all option text on page load, why are you setting it inside onchange event of SELECT element? Why not set it server side while rendering HTML? Maybe i don't understand what you are looking for

Comment: @A.Wolff  because the code not allow me to set it server side.It is a bad written php script 9 years old.So my intention is to use a dirty way to replace the option text.

Comment: @BatuZet , like i said , i messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be what you are looking for:

### DEMO

```
$('select').find('option').each(function () {
    var numInStock = $("body").find("div[valueid=" + this.value + "]").attr("valuestock");
    if (numInStock) {
        $(this).text($(this).text() + '(' + numInStock + ') In Stock');
    } else {
        $(this).text($(this).text() + ' - Out of Stock');
    }
});
```

Comment: EXACTLY!!!!!!!!!!! so less code, i knew it would not be much need.But therefore experts like you exist.I am really thankfull for your help.

Comment: Glad you have fixed your issue ;)